# jQuery.extend an object, whether or not it exists yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The Problem**

I am declaring certain properties of a parent object in undependable different places, such that it is difficult to predict whether the parent object will exist yet when I'm declaring these properties. No matter where this happens, I need the parent object to be created IF it doesn't exist yet, but not re-declared if it does.

**Example**

Say I have this JavaScript happening somewhere:

```
membership = {
    id: 5,
    name: "John"
}
```

And at another point in the code (could be before the above code block or after), I have something like this:

```
membership.level = "gold";
```

I essentially need to be able to have `membership.level` create the `membership` object if doesn't exist yet, but if it does exist, just add the `level` property. Similarly, the first code block needs to work in such a way that if `membership` exists already, it just adds the `id` and `name` properties.

**The Code I've Got So Far**

My solution did not work, but I think you'll be able to see what I'm going for. This is what I tried:

*1st block*

```
membership = $.extend(membership, {
    id: 5,
    name: "John"
});
```

*2nd block*

```
membership = $.extend(membership , {
    level: "gold"
});
```

The above still errors sometimes, when membership is not defined. Is there a way to do this in the way I'm describing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This feels like a bad way to go about this. Always declare variables using `var foo = ...` just so you can come back to the code later and know what's going on. Also, implicitly declared global variables in JavaScript cause cancer (or at least headaches).

Comment: It's not ideal, but it's necessary in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var membership = $.extend({}, membership , {
    level: "gold"
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gJ9d4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
membership = $.extend(membership || {} , {
    level: "gold"
});
```

If membership is undefined, it will create an object.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJ9d4/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/ALVPe/)***

Usually this is done with an `||` operator

```
var membership = membership || { id: 5, name: "John" };
```

Basically, if `membership` is undefined then membership is set equal to the object definition, but if `membership` is defined, then it is just re-assigned.

You could follow this with the extend call if you wish.

```
//this could be used as the extend membership
var membership = membership || { id: 5, name: "John" };
membership = $.extend(membership , {
 level: "gold"
});//this could also be membership.level = "gold";
```